# Грамотно ли будет сказать "Его идентифицируют со мной"?

Tags: грамматика, управление

Грамотно ли будет сказать "Его идентифицируют со мной"?

В значении - "принимают за меня", "считают мной".
Если нет, то как сказать это правильно.
Тут важно подчеркнуть, что не просто ошиблись на улице, а в результате какого-то умозаключения, а то и следственного эксперимента.

Уточнение по результатам первого ответа.
Я не значением слова "идентифицировать" интересовался (оно мне известно), а грамотностью фразы в целом. В частности, Употреблением предлога "С".
А второе - насколько фраза получается двусмысленной. Не получается ли "вместе со мной", "с моей помощью".

Comment: В корпусе есть примеры использования "идентифицировать с". Хотя и немного, [всего 20](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E8%E4%E5%ED%F2%E8%F4%E8%F6%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%F2%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%F1&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=).

Comment: Я видел. Знаю, что употребляют, иначе и вопроса бы не было. Из этих двадцати надо выкинуть несколько, которые не "с", а "с помощью" и т.п. И еще все - сравнительно недавние. У классиков нет. Это тоже "не сближает".

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что так говорить не следует. В применении к людям "идентификация" обычно означает установление личности, опознание, принадлежность человека к группе и т. п. - на основании сопоставления выявленных признаков с известными. В вашем случае чисто формально можно сказать "его ошибочно идентифицируют как меня", "его дела почему-то ассоциируют (связывают мысленно) со мной". Для глагола "идентифицировать" (а он иностранного происхождения и сохраняет некоторые особенности связывания с другими словами) характерно либо отсутствие уточняющих слов (останки идентифицировали = уже известно, чьи), либо указание, в каком качестве, "**как** кто (что)" был идентифицирован человек или напр. находка (аналогично  английскому 'to identify smb./smth. **as**...'). Идентифицирован как Сидоров, как агент саудовской разведки и т. п. Поэтому "его идентифицируют со мной" может прозвучать как "его опознание проводят с моим участием" и надёжнее обойтись без канцеляризмов, сказав "его путают со мной (принимают за меня)".

**P.S.** По типу грамматических связей этот глагол близок к "классифицировать", что может послужить ориентиром в неясных случаях.

*В описи предмет был классифицирован **как** "ювелирное изделие в форме яйца", позже его идентифицировали **как** "яйцо Фаберже, подаренное императрице Николаем II в 19xx году".*

Comment: Так каков ответ?

Comment: (+) "Как меня" интуитивно представляется немногим лучше.  "Как" еще более многозначно (так же, как меня, как и меня - и т.д.). Кстати, запятая в этом случае нужна?! А про грамматические свойства - это откуда?

Comment: Я тоже не считаю такую фразу удачной, это только иллюстрация формально возможного - в противоположность исходной конструкции. Про грамматические связи - просто наблюдение.

Comment: P.S. Запятая не нужна (~ известен как такой-то).

Answer (score 1):

1) Человек может идентифицировать (отождествить) СЕБЯ с кем-то.

Примеры: Некоторые дети идентифицируют себя с Колдуньей.  Исследователи пришли к выводу, что журналисты, как и менеджеры, принадлежа к среднему классу, разделяют их ценности и легче идентифицируют себя с ними, нежели с рабочими.

2) Если идентифицируется ДРУГОЙ ЧЕЛОВЕК, то речь идет об установлении его личности, поэтому фраза "Его идентифицируют" является законченной по смыслу.

3) Фраза  "Его идентифицируют со мной" - это что-то из детективных романов, то есть окружающие будут считать, что данный человек является мной. В определенном контексте содержание предложения понятно и грамматически корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Грамотно. Но лучше – "путают с", то есть, "ошибочно принимают за", конечно, если нет ограничений в русских словах. Если есть подозрения в намеренности, то эту мысль надо излагать отдельно и деликатно.

Comment: Хотелось бы обоснования. А другие варианты меня не интересуют. Читайте, пожалуйста вопрос перед тем как отвечать. Вопрос не в стилистике, а в грамматике.

Comment: Фраза грамотная, но двусмысленная. Не иностранное слово могло бы снять толкование: примеров использования "путать с" гораздо меньше, чем "идентифицировать с".